# Ambiguous flow of node.js program execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please find the code below,

What i am still unable to understand in the code, is that why the browser keeps waiting for 10 seconds before executing the next query. Shouldn't it be just pass the sleep query to the database and then move on to execute the next one immediately?

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

var connection = mysql.createConnection({

    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'pops',    
    dateStrings: 'true',
    multipleStatements: 'true'
});

// Connect to MySQL (if there is an error, report it and terminate the request)
connection.connect (function (err) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)

    if (err !== null)
    {
        console.log('Error '+err.code);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Connection to database successful!');
    }
});

 connection.query("SELECT sleep(10);", function(err, rows) {

        // There was a error or not?
        if (err !== null)
        {
            console.log("Query Rrror:" + err);
        }
        else
        {
            // Shows the result on console window              
              console.log("called after 10 seconds");              
        } 
 });

 connection.query("SELECT * FROM team", function(error, result) {

        // There was a error or not?
        if (error !== null)
        {
            console.log("Query Rrror:" + error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Shows the result on console window
              response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
              length = result.length - 1;

              for(var i = 0; i <= length; i++)
              {
                  row_obj = result[i];

                  team_id = row_obj.id;
                  team_name = row_obj.team_name;
                  team_color = row_obj.color;
                  created_at = row_obj.created_at;

                  response.write('Team ID: ' + team_id + '<br />');
                  response.write('Team Name: ' + team_name + '<br />');
                  response.write('Team Color: ' + team_color + '<br />');
                  response.write('Creation Date: ' + created_at + '<br />');
                  response.write('<br /><br />');
              }

              response.end("OK");
        } 
 });

 // Close connection
 connection.end();

 }).listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Huh, I haven't tried `mysql` npm, but isn't `.connect` and `.query` works asynchronously?

Comment: I think what Pedro answered is correct. Could you add the output that you see in the console? This will show what steps are being executed/ended and on what order.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create the mysql connection outside the httpRequest handler.

And yes, Node.JS will execute both queries without waiting, but what I think that is happening, is that `node-mysql` is queuing the query.

Comment: well actually what i feel is that the sleep operation makes the node js to go in a blocking mode, and it just blocks anyrequest until 10 seconds are over. am I correct?

Comment: It's not the Node.JS, could be the module you are using.